# Only a type can be imported. org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook resolves to a package

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp, apache-poi

Trying to use Apache POI in a Eclipse JSP project. The POI jar is in the project's Java Resources Library list.

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
```

at run the following error occurs:

> An error occurred at line: 7 in the
>   generated java file Only a type can be
>   imported.
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
>   resolves to a package

Any ideas?  Thanks
Don Lawton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message indicates that the class could not be found on the classpath of your deployed application. Did you make sure that the POI jar is in your WEB-INF/lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me, even when the needed jars were indeed in the WEB-INF folder.
I was using the provided server in SpringSource ToolSuite (STS). It took me several attempts to clean, republish, etc... before it finally worked.